# Two ground wires from fixture in instructions but only one unattached

Tags: wiring, lighting, light-fixture, grounding

I am currently installing an Artika 4-Pendant light fixture - Milton 4 but am running into issues while wiring it. In the instructions it indicates that "Connect the ground wire (G) to the two ground wires (G) on the fixture" but when looking at the fixture only one ground wire is disconnected at one end and the other ground wire is visible but already connected to the wires and fixture itself.

The only way I could see connecting the second wire is by kinking it into a U shape and placing that into the wire nut with the other ground wires but the diagram only has 2 wires coming from the fixture and if I kink it then I would have three wires from the fixture (I also feel like this would probably damage the wire anyways). This is my first time doing any wiring and even after doing research I couldn't find a scenario like this.

From the manual
[image: Instructions]

The fixture itself
[image]

Comment: Why not contact the manufacturer. They have a website with a Customer Service section.

Comment: Think they did not update manual.  If bare wire is only attached to the green wires, then it should be connected to second unattached bare wire at the fitting, so will need only one ground connected to ground from ceiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is OK, as the greens on the pendant lights are connected via 1 bare copper to the fixture.

Normally, this would require both of the coppers to come from the same connection point if the shades are metal.
if the shades are non metallic, it would not need the lower ground, but the metal canopy that they hang from needs to be grounded.

Since the mfg. has already bonded the 3 shades, all you need to do is connect your ground to the unused ground and everything will be grounded.

I have found the same instructions with different fixtures because they may be being manufactured in a non English speaking place or what ever your language is I know this site is world wide but colors based on normal North America power.

Comment: I ended up calling the support line and they also confirmed that this is the case. Manual wasn't updated to reflect the one ground wire. Accepting this answer as it was spot on to what customer service said, thanks for the help!